# Aplicar background-color a Input con numero hexadecimal guardado en base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, css

Les comento, en mi DB tengo una tabla `Categorias` la cual contiene, `CategoriaID`, `CategoriaDescription` y `CategoriaColor`, mi duda es, al desplegar las diferentes categorías en inputs ejemplo

```
 <input type="button" value="'$row['CategoryDescription']'">
```

¿como puedo ponerle a cada una el color de fondo con que se hizo el registro?

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? Por favor, muestranos algo del código que tengas hasta el momento para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: A que te refieres con desplegar categorias en inputs, lo normal es que los muestres en una tabla

Comment: hasta ahora solo hacia la llamada de los campos de la base de datos, e imprimia los resultados en inputs como se los comente, los inputs debido a que las categorias aun deben desplegar cierta informacion al pulsarlos, es por eso que lo hice en botones de la siguiente manera. 
 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM PECategory ORDER BY CategoryLvl";
 
 $i = 0;
 
 foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row){
  
  echo '<input type="button" value="'.$row['CategoryDescription'].'" class="cat'.$i.'">
     <input type="text" value="'.$row['CategoryColor'].'">';
     
  $i++;
  
 }

Comment: las dos opciones que me han comentado me han servido. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, no publiques una respuesta diciendo "gracias". En su lugar, **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que consideres como la mejor solución a tu problema. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/110799)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No coloques la propiedad en "value", colocalo en style. Ejemplo

`<input type="button" style="background-color:<?php $row['CategoryDescription'] ?>">`

Answer (score 1):

cuando lo estes imprimiendo puedes ponerlo asi

```
<input type="button" value="'.$row['CategoryDescription'].'" style="background:#'.$row['CategoriaColor'].'">
```

solo si el color viene como hexadecimal ejemplo **889900**